# Review validation fails in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have used the package **react-native-rate** for rate my application in ios store/google playstore. but it ignores in the below cases.

CASE 1:
1) While showing Rating prompt, when the user press the OK Button to add a review, Application will redirect to ios store/google playstore.
2) If the user exit without adding review, then application considering as review added.
3) Could you please let me know how to validate the added the review or not.

CASE 2 :
1) Currently, I have implemented based on AsyncStorage. so if the user accessing the app more than one device, then the review alert will be asked in each device.
2) Could you please let me know, how to identify the user has added the review in any of the device or not.

```
import Rate, { AndroidMarket } from 'react-native-rate';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

```
const ratingApp = async () => {
    const isAlreadyRate = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isAlreadyRate');
    const countStartApp = await AsyncStorage.getItem('countStartApp');
    const count = countStartApp ? parseInt(countStartApp) : 1;
    if (!isAlreadyRate && count % 10 === 0) {
      Alert.alert('App Rating', 'Please give us your opinion!', [
        {
          text: 'Later',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              let options = {
                AppleAppID: '************',
                GooglePackageName: '***************',
                preferredAndroidMarket: AndroidMarket.Google,
                preferInApp: false,
                openAppStoreIfInAppFails: true,
              };
              Rate.rate(options, success => {
                if (success) {
                   AsyncStorage.setItem('isAlreadyRate', 'true');                 
                }
              });
            }, 1000);
          },
        },
      ]);
    }
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('countStartApp', `${count + 1}`);
  }
```

Comment: There is no way you can get detail of whether user has added rating or not. However now you can use in-build review popup for both platform using [rn-in-app-review](https://github.com/ravirupareliya/rn-in-app-review)

Comment: Thanks for your response. but once I reviewed and changed my device (mobile), then the popup again appeared. Is there way to stop the popup. I am using AsyncStorage for stored locally to control the popup, once the user clicked the ok button. but my problem was when the user was changed the device or clear data for app then the popup again appeared. Is there way to control this one.